# Assignment directive not assigning new value to a symbol in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

Why doesn't the following code assign new value to a symbol `X` using Assignment Directive ( **=** ) in emu8086:

```
.model small
.data

        X = 8

.code
.startup

       mov ax, @data
       mov ds, ax

       mov bx, X

       X = 6      

       mov bx, X 

       mov ah, 02h
       mov dx, bx   
       add dx, 48
       int 21h     ; It should display 6 but instead it display 8. 

       mov ah, 04ch
       int 21h

end
```

Comment: Appears to be a bug or deficiency in EMU8086. With MASM and TASM you are allowed to redefine a constant value that has been defined with `=` . Seems EMU8086 takes the original value and ignores subsequent changes

Comment: Yes i check it in **GUI TURBO ASSEMBLER** and there it worked. Should i report it ?

Comment: I have no idea if EMU8086 is still maintained. I couldn't find an email address or other mechanism to report on bugs.

Comment: emu8086 is full of bugs :( i found two of them ( including this one )

Comment: I'm happy to upvote anything pointing out reasons not to use emu8086, including bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EMU8086 has a bug/deficiency. Your interpretation of how the `=` directive works is [correct](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0130_equ_directive.htm):

> Integers defined with the = directive can be redefined with another value in your source code, but those defined with EQU cannot.

If you compile this with *MASM* or *TASM* the code should work as you expect by displaying `6` instead of `8`.

EMU8086 hasn't been updated in years and I do not believe it is currently being maintained. It doesn't appear there is a bug reporting system or bug related email address associated with the product.

If you are looking for a reason not to use EMU8086 then the lack of maintenance; known bugs; and limited BIOS and DOS Int 21h compatibility should be reasons to find other tools to do the job. Writing 32-bit and 64-bit code native to the OS you are on is a more ideal approach. EMU8086 is a good instructional tool, but shouldn't be used for any serious work.

Comment: Well i am just learning assembly 8086 i am not planing to write serious code in it but if i do then i would prefer TASM for the same. btw thanks for the answer appreciated 

Comment: btw i did not learnd the difference between `EQU` & `=` directives on the net instead i learnd it on a book namely **The 8088 and 8086 Microprocessors**